# AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode throw new exception in single tenant application using ASP.NET MVC using Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory

I tried [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-build-aspnetmvc-apps/5-exercise-add-auth) because I want to use the Microsoft Graph API to create massive teams in Microsoft Teams.
The only difference with the tutorial is that I used the next choice in Authentication section of Azure AD admin center:

```
"Accounts in this organizational directory only (myuniversity only - Single tenant)"
```

Because of this I changed my code to use endpoint for single tenant

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            
            ClientId = appId,
            //Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0",//
            Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0",
            Scope = $"openid email profile offline_access {graphScopes}",
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // For demo purposes only, see below
                ValidateIssuer = false

                // In a real multi-tenant app, you would add logic to determine whether the
                // issuer was from an authorized tenant
                //ValidateIssuer = true,
                //IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, tvp) =>
                //{
                //  if (MyCustomTenantValidation(issuer))
                //  {
                //    return issuer;
                //  }
                //  else
                //  {
                //    throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("Invalid issuer");
                //  }
                //}
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync
            }
        }
    );
}
```

After authentication of the user the code I run to `OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync` method but got an exception in `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode` method

Here is the method

```
private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
{
    var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
        .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
        .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
        .Build();
    var accounts = await idClient.GetAccountsAsync();
    string message;
    string debug;

    try
    {
        string[] scopes = graphScopes.Split(' ');

        var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();

        message = "Access token retrieved.";
        debug = result.AccessToken;
    }
    catch (MsalException ex)
    {
        message = "AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync threw an exception";
        debug = ex.Message;
    }

    var queryString = $"message={message}&debug={debug}";
    if (queryString.Length > 2048)
    {
        queryString = queryString.Substring(0, 2040) + "...";
    }

    notification.HandleResponse();
    notification.Response.Redirect($"/Home/Error?{queryString}");
}
```

The exception is:

> AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync threw an exception
>
> AADSTS50194: Application 'application id'(ASP.NET Graph Tutorial) is
> not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of the /common
> endpoint is not supported for such applications created after
> '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the
> application to be multi-tenant. Trace ID:
> 5f0fbf2e-5d63-40d4-a833-ca8627a02d00
>
> Correlation ID: 3ec4ec7b-0c86-4e2b-a053-9823f977499d Timestamp:
> 2021-02-16 20:21:03Z

I want to use single-tenant authentication for my organization only

Comment: please try to use the code `var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId) .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri) .WithClientSecret(appSecret).WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}").Build()` to create client

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Comment: @JimXu's answer is correct.
The sample code requires you reference the single tenant on ConfigureAuth and OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to require AD token from one specific  tenant with MSAL.NET, you can tell the SDK from which tenant to obtain the token by mentioning the specific Authority. For more details, please refer to  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.abstractapplicationbuilder-1.withauthority?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Identity_Client_AbstractApplicationBuilder_1_WithAuthority_System_String_System_Boolean_).

For example

```
 private static string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppId"];
        private static string appSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppSecret"];
        private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
        private static string graphScopes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppScopes"];
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = appId,
                    Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>/v2.0",
                    Scope = $"openid email profile offline_access {graphScopes}",
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        // For demo purposes only, see below
                        ValidateIssuer = false

                        // In a real multi-tenant app, you would add logic to determine whether the
                        // issuer was from an authorized tenant
                        //ValidateIssuer = true,
                        //IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, tvp) =>
                        //{
                        //  if (MyCustomTenantValidation(issuer))
                        //  {
                        //    return issuer;
                        //  }
                        //  else
                        //  {
                        //    throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("Invalid issuer");
                        //  }
                        //}
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
        {
            var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                 .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                 .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
                 .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>")
                 .Build();

            string message;
            string debug;

            try
            {
                string[] scopes = graphScopes.Split(' ');

                var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                    scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();

                message = "Access token retrieved.";
                debug = result.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                message = "AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync threw an exception";
                debug = ex.Message;
            }

            var queryString = $"message={message}&debug={debug}";
            if (queryString.Length > 2048)
            {
                queryString = queryString.Substring(0, 2040) + "...";
            }

            notification.HandleResponse();
            notification.Response.Redirect($"/Home/Error?{queryString}");
        }

        private Task OnAuthenticationFailedAsync(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            notification.HandleResponse();
            string redirect = $"/Home/Error?message={notification.Exception.Message}";
            if (notification.ProtocolMessage != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription))
            {
                redirect += $"&debug={notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription}";
            }
            notification.Response.Redirect(redirect);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```